# execute all terminal commands in one terminal window in background with php

Tags: php, linux, bash, terminal

I'm using a terminal app in my PHP project and i want to send commands continuously to the same terminal window in background. now i can run my terminal app with `proc_open`, but when app run user can send another command (like -w, -d, -m , ...) for see application abilities, how can i do this?
Here is my code for execute commands in terminal:

```
$cwd = 'path/to/script.php';
$command = 'php script.php';
$descriptorspec =
    [
        0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
        1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
        2 => ['pipe', 'w']
    ];

$process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);
```

now after this, users can execute another commands in this terminal window for see another options.

Comment: Due to the involvement of `php` i am a bit unsure about the answer. But check out this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell). May help you.